# Sort a data in a pivot table according to the number of rows on another column

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

My question is also the title of my query.. i hope you can help me.
How do you sort a data in the pivot table in google sheets according to the number of rows you have on another column?
In the image, i want to sort the team leaders' names according to the number missing employees.
The sort options available in the pivot table don't seem to help. [Table sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAde3.png)

The sort options in the pivot table couldn't do what i'm looking to.

Comment: **Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.** Would you please edit your question to include the sample data in the body of the question, and also include an example of the desired outcome.